# Review Options in Low Quality Posts

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

I encountered an issue when reviewing low quality posts. When giving a reason to reject the review, you sometimes get 6 options to choose from, while at other times, you only get 2.

What I normally do in my case is skip the question and move on to review the next question.

Is this a bug or is it there for a purpose?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't *need* to leave a comment while recommending deletion, but for posts made by *new* users it might help them in getting acquainted in the ways of Stack Overflow. The system provides predefined comments for the six most common cases of low quality posts.

The reason why most of these are disabled for *old* posts is also mentioned in the dialog:

> This answer has been on the site for quite a while now; it probably won't benefit from commentary. If you think it could be fixed, go back and leave a comment explaining the problem.

If the old posts *are* low quality, don't hesitate to click <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> instead of <kbd>Skip</kbd>.

Comment: I still love to give a reason for deleting the posts, for the new users to learn the norms on SO. But thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @dev.mi perfect, that's the *go back and leave a comment explaining the problem.*

Comment: @dev.mi Chances are, if the post is very old and the user only has ~1 rep, that the author hasn't visited for a while. Sometimes it's just the one answer and they leave. There's no harm in leaving a comment, though.

Answer (score 9):

This is about age.

If the post is has been on the site for a while, then only "No comment needed" and "This is a link-only answer" are available.

Judging by personal experience, it seems to be the case if the post is over 6 months old. This would make some sense, as it is also the time used for the "Excavator" and "Archeologist" badges; implying that "6 months" is "old" in Stack Overflow time.