# "This is a thank you comment" radio button not appearing on Low quality answer review queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, low-quality-posts

**Scenario 01**

I got the below answer (image 01) in the review. It's a thank you comment on the above post. But the system doesn't allow me to add "thank you" comment message (image 2).

This did not only occur on this post, but on several other ones too.

**Image 01/ Post**
[image: post]

**Image 2 /Flag I got**
[image]

---

**Scenario 02**

**Post**
[image]

**Flag pop-up**

[image]

Comment: Working as intended: see the message at the bottom of the popup without most of the canned comments.  It's an older post that's unlikely to benefit from commentary.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why the options are missing? The first dialog states: "This answer has been on the site for quite a while now; it probably won't benefit from commentary....".

Comment: @RyanM agree with you. Explain why **This is a link-only answer (and not spam)** on the message. If you say commenting, **Thank you...** is not applicable since it's too old, then why does **Link only...** exist. Is it utterly irrelevant, right? Not an argument. I am just clearing my point.

Comment: My theory behind that one is that link-only answers are salvageable: the poster can fix them by editing in the information that's currently behind the link.  The comment may prompt them to do so.  The others really aren't fixable: the comment is more of a "hey, don't do this again."

Comment: Surely this decision is conscious and documented somewhere?

Comment: Duplicate of: [Review Options in Low Quality Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327597/review-options-in-low-quality-posts). See also: [Can we stop posting LQP auto-comments on answers from SO's dark ages?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298542/8967612).

Comment: @Karl Yes. See the second link in my previous comment.